# Django Queryset - rename original values and re-use original value names

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm completing a challenge for a job and I'm a little confused with this endpoint's response.

I have the following models:

- `Attribute`
- `AttributeValue`
- `ProductAttribute`

I need to get all attributes that are linked to a given product ID. I have managed to get the values but I can't give them the correct names in the response. The relevant code is in the `get_attributes_from_product` function:

```
# src/api/viewsets/attribute.py

from django.db.models import F
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from api import errors
from api.models import Attribute, AttributeValue, ProductAttribute
from api.serializers import AttributeSerializer, AttributeValueSerializer, AttributeValueExtendedSerializer
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class AttributeViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    list: Return a list of attributes
    retrieve: Return a attribute by ID.
    """
    queryset = Attribute.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttributeSerializer

    @action(detail=False, url_path='values/<int:attribute_id>')
    def get_values_from_attribute(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Get Values Attribute from Attribute ID
        """
        attribute_id = int(kwargs['attribute_id'])

        # Filter queryset to find all values for attribute
        response = AttributeValue.objects.filter(attribute_id=attribute_id).values(
          'attribute_value_id', 'value')

        # Return response
        if response.exists():
          return Response(response, 200)
        else:
          return Response(response, 204)

    @action(detail=False, url_path='inProduct/<int:product_id>')
    def get_attributes_from_product(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Get all Attributes with Product ID
        """
        product_id = int(kwargs['product_id'])

        # Filter all attributes in product
        response = ProductAttribute.objects.filter(product_id=product_id).annotate(
          original_attribute_value_id=F('attribute_value_id'),
          original_attribute_value=F('attribute_value__value')).values(
          attribute_name=F('attribute_value__attribute_id__name'),
          attribute_value_id=F('attribute_value_id'),
          attribute_value=F('attribute_value__value')
        )

        # Return response
        if response.exists():
          return Response(response, 200)
        else:
          return Response(response, 204)
```

If I change `attribute_value_id=F('attribute_value_id')` and `attribute_value=F('attribute_value__value')` to `attribute_value_id1=F('attribute_value_id')` and `attribute_value1=F('attribute_value__value')` the response is successful and all the values are correct, but obviously the key names are wrong.

It should return the following keys: `attribute_name`, `attribute_value_id` and `attribute_value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The django ORM will not overwrite existing model attributes with the names of annotated fields.

In order to use names that collide with existing model attributes, you need to use a
serializer class or just format the queryset rows before returning the response.

[An example of using a serializer can be found in the django rest-framework
documentation.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

Without using a queryset, you can use a `list` of `dict` objects in the response. This
is a shortcut though, and using a serializer would probably be better.

```py
class AttributeViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    # ...

    def render_product_attribute_row(self, row):
        row["attribute_value_id"] = row.pop("tmp_attribute_value_id")
        row["attribute_value"] = row.pop("tmp_attribute_value")
        return row

    @action(detail=False, url_path='inProduct/<int:product_id>')
    def get_attributes_from_product(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_id = int(kwargs['product_id'])

        queryset = ProductAttribute.objects.filter(product_id=product_id)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            original_attribute_value_id=F('attribute_value_id'),
            original_attribute_value=F('attribute_value__value'),
        )
        queryset = queryset.values(
            attribute_name=F('attribute_value__attribute_id__name'),
            tmp_attribute_value_id=F('attribute_value_id'),
            tmp_attribute_value=F('attribute_value__value'),
        )

        if queryset.exists():
            status_code = 200
        else:
            status_code = 204

        response = [self.render_product_attribute_row(row) for row in queryset]

        return Response(response, status_code)
```

Comment: Thanks, Damon! This really helped me out. Reading up on serializer classes now and trying to see how I can do it that way, if I don't get it right in time I'll stick with the solution above. Appreciate it.